# C# determining generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

I have several templated objects that all implement the same interface:

I.E.

```
MyObject<datatype1> obj1;
MyObject<datatype2> obj2;
MyObject<datatype3> obj3;
```

I want to store these objects in a List... I think I would do that like this:

```
private List<MyObject<object>> _myList;
```

I then want to create a function that takes 1 parameter, being a datatype, to see if an object using that datatype exists in my list.... sorta clueless how to go about this. In Pseudo code it would be:

```
public bool Exist(DataType T)
{
   return (does _myList contain a MyObject<T>?);
}
```

**Some Clarification....**

My interface is `IMyObject<T>`, my objects are `MyObject<T>`. I have a new class `MyObjectManager` which I need to have a List of `MyObject<T>` stored within. I need a function to check if a `MyObject<T>` exists in that list. The type `T` are datatypes which were auto-generated using T4.... POCO classes from my Entity Data Model.

Comment: What if it contains a `MyObject<U>` and `U` inherits `T`?

Comment: Well my U is auto generated using T4 and EF POCO classes.

Comment: Do the classes inherit each-other?

Comment: No, by default they do not inherit from anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a generic function:

```
public bool Exists<T>() where T : class {
    return _myList.OfType<MyObject<T>>().Any();
}
```

Note that this requires that you know `T` at compile-time.

If all you have is a `System.Type` object at runtime, you'll need to use reflection:

```
public bool Exists(Type t) {
    var objectOfT = typeof(MyObject<>).MakeGenericType(t);

    return _myList.Any(o => o.GetType() == objectOfT);
}
```

Note, however, that a `List<MyObject<object>>` *cannot* hold a `MyObject<SomeType>`.
You need to change the list to a `List<object>`, or make `MyObject` implement or inherit a non-generic type and make the list contain that type.

Comment: My class that stores the list will not have a generic type, However the T in MyObject<T> is known at compile time and the namespace for these objects are referenced in this class. When I try your first example it says The type T must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter. I want T to be a generic type so I can pass in any datatype, whether it be int, string, etc

Comment: You need to add a `where T : class` contstraint, to match the constraint in `MyObject`.

Answer (score 1):

How about an extension method?

```
public static bool HasAny(this IEnumerable source, Type type) {
    foreach (object item in source)
        if (item != null && item.GetType().Equals(type))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
bool hasDataType1 = myList.HasAny(typeof(MyObject<datatype1>));
```

Note that if you don't want to have to type out `typeof(...)` -- i.e., if you basically want your `Exist` method to **only** care about objects of type `MyObject<T>`, I'd go with something like SLaks's answer:

```
public static bool Exist<T>(this IEnumerable source) {
    return source.OfType<MyObject<T>>().Any();
}
```

Also, SLaks is right that you really can't have a `List<MyObject<object>>` that's full of anything other than objects of type `MyObject<object>` or some derived class (and `MyObject<datatype1>`, etc. do **not** derive from `MyObject<object>` -- generics don't work that way).

Another way I might suggest to work around the whole "you can't get the type of a generic class using a `System.Type` object without using reflection" issue would be this: Make your `MyObject<T>` implement a non-generic interface, like this:

```
public interface IMyObject {
    Type DataType { get; }
}

public class MyObject<T> : IMyObject<T>, IMyObject {
    public Type DataType {
        get { return typeof(T); }
    }
}
```

Then your list could be a `List<IMyObject>` (the non-generic interface) and your `Exist` method could look like this:

```
public static bool Exist<T>(this IEnumerable source, Type type) {
    return source.OfType<IMyObject>().Any(x => x.DataType.Equals(type));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since they all implement the same interface, instead of casting them to object and calling GetType (which can be expensive) why not add a property to your interface called class name (or something)?  Then you can use the linq in order to grab that property.  And don't forget `using System.Linq`

```
using System.Linq;

public bool Exist(List<IMyInterface> objects, IMyInterface typeToCheck)
{
   return objects.Any(t => t.ObjectName == typeToCheck.ObjectName);
}
```

Comment: My interface is IMyInterface<T>